# Remove the subfolder from the url path, given that there is no slash at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L]
```

it removes /pages/ from the url to the pages

but when i open link without the slash at the end:

```
site.com/contacts
```

it is redirected to

```
site.com/pages/contacts/
```

Is there a way to fix this?

---

*I've tried different results, most often other options cause a redirect to site.com/index.php ( site.com/pages/index.php)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because `pages/contacts` is a directory and Apache `mod_dir` module is adding a trailing slash after request to a directory.

You can check for directory presence and add a trailing `/` via a rule before rewrite to `pages/`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if pages/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to use a different browser or remove cache data from your browser to test this rule to avoid old cache.

Comment: Ooh, thank you very much, I also tried to add the slash forcibly, but it doesn't work quite adequately. Your version works.